# what is this function work in admin grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid

I want to know what is this function functionality in admin grid.

```
protected function _afterLoadCollection()
{
    $this->getCollection()->walk('afterLoad');
    parent::_afterLoadCollection();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_afterLoadCollection` is called automatically in the grid block.
It gives you an additional callback for the grid collection.
`$this->getCollection()->walk('afterLoad');` calls `afterLoad` method for each item in the collection.

Usually, this `afterLoad` method is called when calling `load` on an object but not on a collection.
This code forces the `afterLoad` call for each item even if we are not calling `load` on each of them.

Answer (score 2):

> It call afterLoad method on each object from collection class which is similar as below

```
foreach($collection as $_object) {
     $_object->afterLoad();
}
```

as Marius said Usually, this `afterLoad` method is called when calling `load` on an object but not on a collection.
This code forces the afterLoad call for each item even if we are not calling load on each of them